# Взаимодействие диалогов

Tags: android

Как создать диалог в диалоге(при нажатии на некую кнопку первого диалога, появляется второй), чтобы первый получил какие либо данные из второго(т.е. второй закрывается)? Возможно ли это сделать?

Comment: Используйте DialogFragment и вызывайте сколько хотите диалогов, комуникации между фрагментами через `ChildFragmentManager`, Недавно здесь был вопрос по этой теме.

Comment: @pavlofff А можете про жизненный цикл рассказать в этой ситуации? Допустим нажимаю на кнопку первого диалога, появляется перед лицом другой диалог. Что происходит с первым? И что в это время происходит с фрагментом/активити с учётом двух диалогов?

Comment: видимо ничего. DialogFragment появляется как `View` в текущем активити наверное, по крайней мере ее методы onPause() onResume() не вызыаются при появлении диалога. Можете потестировать, накидать логов в методы жизненного цикла и посмотреть